# How to use MAX on a table with millions of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I've a table that contains all the information related to transactions , it has the deviceID making sales and also the transaction number ( This table has millions of rows). I've a list of some DeviceID on a temp table and I'm doing a join to the transactions table to get the max Transaction number but it takes forever to display results. Is there a better way to write the sql syntax to get the results in less time? Maybe doing a subquery into the same transactions table to get the MAX values , Any idea will be highly appreciated. My current code is below:

```
select a.DeviceID,
MAX(tq.Transaction_number)
from Datawarehouse.DBO.Transactions tq with (nolock)
/*The #Temp1 table contains the Device IDs we want to get the MAX transaction number ,
the total amount of Devices are between 1 and 1000 */
inner join #Temp1 a on a.DeviceID = tq.DeviceID
--We only want the MAX transaction number for sales ( Not Refunds)
where tq.Transaction_type = 'SALES'
```

Comment: It would help if we had the DDL for the tables and indexes, and the actual execution plan. (Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.)

Comment: That is not valid syntax so I don't know how it could take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.DeviceID, tt.Transaction_no
from #temp1 t cross apply ( 
     select max(tr.Transaction_number) Transaction_no
     from Datawarehouse.DBO.Transactions tr
     where t.DeviceID = tr.DeviceID and 
           tr.Transaction_type = 'SALES'
) tt;
```

However, this will help you if you have index on (`DeviceID`, 
`Transaction_type`
 &`Transaction_number`) and don't forgot to `SET NOCOUNT` prior to the query especially when you are working with SSMS.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, I'm still ding some test , I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this works better:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(tq.Transaction_number)
        from Datawarehouse.DBO.Transactions tq
        where t.DeviceID = tq.DeviceID and tq.Transaction_type = 'SALES'
       )
from #temp1 t;
```

In particular, you want a composite index on `Transactions(DeviceID, Transaction_type, Transaction_number desc)`.

Comment: I've 450 Devices on temp1 table and when I run this , it gets stuck loading , It took 3 minutes to display the data

Comment: Wouldn't descending `Transaction_number` in the index be better for `Max()`?

Comment: I've noticed that the main issue is this part: tq.Transaction_type = 'SALES' , it does a full scan on the table ( removing this will reduce the time like -3 minutes)

Comment: @JoshSama . . . Do you have the index on the table?

Answer (score 1):

I think propper indexing will help. Look at the [Example-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/btQJ5tm8djfXGR6efrRvck/0)

Query:

```
Select
    d.device_id,
    MAX( t.transaction_id ) transaction_id
From
    devices d
JOIN
    transactions t
    ON t.device_id = d.device_id
    # AND transaction_types = ...
GROUP BY
    d.device_id;
```

Comment: use `EXPLAIN Select` to get details on key usage

Comment: You are missing Transaction_type = 'SALES'

Comment: ye, thx for pointing out, added comment where it would be placed

Comment: Thanks all,  I'm still ding some test , I'll keep you updatedd

Comment: Get your results on [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) much easier to help like this